# Переделать hover на click функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как переделать этот скрипт с `.hover()` на `.click()` функцию?

```
$(".container-top-catalog-area-item").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".container-top-catalog-area-item-main-button").addClass("active");
    $(this).find(".child-dropdown").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".container-top-catalog-area-item-main-button").removeClass("active");
    $(this).find(".child-dropdown").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: а вы `.click()` пробовали ? https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя `.on("click", function)` (или `.click(function)`) и `.toggleClass()` + `.fadeToggle()`:

```js
$(".container-top-catalog-area-item").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find(".container-top-catalog-area-item-main-button").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).find(".child-dropdown").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.container-top-catalog-area-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-top-catalog-area-item">
    <div class="container-top-catalog-area-item-main-button">button</div>
    <div class="child-dropdown">dropdown</div>
</div>
<div class="container-top-catalog-area-item">
    <div class="container-top-catalog-area-item-main-button">button</div>
    <div class="child-dropdown">dropdown</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А как сделать что бы dropdown был только у того контейнера который в данный момент активен, а остальные контейнеры уходили в display: none? Пример bootsrap dropdown menu

Comment: @Димон _bootsrap dropdown menu_ я не искал, но [пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zqyvyf3/) сделал. Если планируются ещё какие-то доработки, то попробуйте сначала сделать их сами, и если что-то конкретное не получится - задать новый вопрос.